# MacOS error code -8058

Tags: macos

Got this error while trying to copy & paste a folder from my NAS to my Mac using Finder on MacOS 10.13.2:

> The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred
>   (error code -8058).

Where are these mystery codes kept?  I tried google, tried the macerror utility in Terminal, tried osstatus.com, even tried searching opensource.apple.com - no luck.  Is there someplace to lookup Mac error codes?

Comment: There's no centralized official source. Best I know of is just Google.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these codes are defined in the `MacErrors.h` header file. It might be that you need Xcode installed to have that header file on your system, so you can look it up online here:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacErrors.h

It lists a huge number of error codes with a short explanation.

Some error codes are not defined in this header file, but instead in other, similar header files for various subsystems. For example `AppKitErrors.h`, `FoundationErrors.h`, `CoreDataErrors.h`, etc.

Unfortunately your error code `-8058` is not defined in `MacErrors.h`.